# Not catching NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping fixtures of one website and then using another website to check each team's form. The issue I am having is that not all teams exist on the form website and I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` for the teams whose `xPath` clearing doesn't exist on the URL not found page. I am trying to catch the exception but the program still breaks.

I have added a try catch but it doesn't solve my problem, the program breaks as soon as it arrives as a non-found team.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < fixtures.getAwayTeams().size(); i++)
 {
     driver.navigate().to(FORMURL.concat( (fixtures.getAwayTeams().get(i)).replace( ' ', '+' )));          
     for (int j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
        String xPath = FORMXPATHONE.concat( String.valueOf( j ) ).concat(FORMXPATHTWO);
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)));
            forms = driver.findElementsByXPath( xPath );
            } catch(NoSuchElementException | StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            awayTeamForm.add("No Form for Team");
            }
        for (WebElement languageElement : forms) {
            ArrayList <String> wld = new ArrayList<String>();
            wld.add( languageElement.getText() );
            String listedForm = String.join(",", wld );
            awayTeamForm.add(listedForm);
        }
    }
    }
 }
```

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="results"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]

Comment: You probably catch the wrong `NoSuchElementException`. There is the default `java.util.NoSuchElementException` which you probably catch, while the code throws a `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that the element is present on the page or not by first fetching the element list and then checking the size of that list, if its greater than 0 then the element is present else the element is not present on the page. By this you don't need to catch the exception as well.

You can do it like:

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xPath"));
if(elementList.size()>0){
    // Element is present
}
else{
    // Element is not present
}
```

Comment: As I am doing this first
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)));`
Will I not get the exception when it cannot see the element?

Comment: No it doesn't work(which you are facing as well) because when the element is not present on the page it throws a null pointer exception. This only works when the element is present on the page but is not visible. In your case, the element is not there on the page, so you need to go with the approach that i have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Although I don't know why it is missing the exceptions, this solution does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `try-catch` statement looks fine. Which means, the issue has to be somewhere else.

You are using selenium, which means there are two Exceptions called NoSuchElementException available. Check your imports. Most likely the problem you have is, that you do import `java.util.NoSuchElementException` instead of `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: I have checked and I have imported org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException; and not java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: That is strage. Could you post the complete StackTrace? Maybe there is something in there that gives a better hint.

Comment: I may have looked at this wrong. It appears I am getting a TimeoutException caused by NoSuchElementException, perhaps I need to catch a TimeoutException?

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="results"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]

Answer (score 0):

Try catch the whole loop body and debug to see if you are catching the right exception and on the right line.
Are you sure that only

```
forms = driver.findElementsByXPath( xPath );
```

can raise the exception?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)));
        forms = driver.findElementsByXPath( xPath );
        } catch(NoSuchElementException | StaleElementReferenceException | TimeoutException e) {
            awayTeamForm.add("No Form for Team");
    }
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference of <td> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html